# Does $\sigma(\frac{m}{n})=\frac{\sigma(m)}{\sigma(n)}$ where $\sigma$ is the sum of divisor function?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function

My question is the same as with the title. Kindly help me prove the statement below if it is true.

What I tried: For specific value of $m$ and $n$ the equality seems to hold.

Does $\sigma(\frac{m}{n})=\frac{\sigma(m)}{\sigma(n)}$ where $\sigma$ is the sum of divisor function?

If not what are the conditions for $m$ and $n$ such that the above condition is true.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do u define it if m/n is not an integer ?

Comment: true when $m/n$ is an integer AND $\gcd(n, m/n) = 1$

Comment: In general, no.  This is $\sigma(a)\sigma(b) = \sigma(ab)$.  True if $a,b$ are relatively prime, but not true in general.

Comment: For a counterexample, take $m=4,n=2$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Specially to Sir Will Jagy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let $N(k)=k$ for all $k$ so that $N$ is a completely multiplicative function. by a well-known result in the elementary theory of arithmetic functions, this implies that
$$
\sigma(n)=\sum_{d|n}N(d)
$$
is also a multiplicative function. so, as Will Jagy pointed out, if $n|m$ and $\gcd(n,\frac{m}{n}=1)$ we have
$$
\sigma(m)=\sigma(n\frac{m}{n})=\sigma(n)\sigma(\frac{m}{n})
$$
from which the result stated follows

Comment: Nice answer. Now I know. Till next time.